# revert commit deletion after a git reset --hard HEAD~1

Tags: git, repository

I deleted a commit accidentally using:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

I want to know if there is a way I can revert this and recover my commit. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ho I find the answer! I did not knew I can use `git reflog` it will show your all your commits included the deleted commits, then you can reset to it like:

`git reset HEAD@{N}`

Where `N` is the number that reflog shows you.